# How to implement a dynamic array of object pointers? "expression must be a modifiable lvalue"

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic

I'm a c++ student and this is my second post here. I'm working on a class whose job is to maintain an array of object pointers. (That way a pointer can be passed in and added to the array, instead of the entire object.) 
The array is supposed to be dynamic but I'm running into some errors when I try to dynamically allocate memory for it. The following code produces the error "expression must be a modifiable lvalue" at *studArray*, as marked.

```
    #ifndef MYCLASS_H
    #define MYCLASS_H
    #include "Student.h"

    class myClass{
    private:
        Student* studArray[5];  
        int howMany;
        int max;
    public:
        myClass(){
            Student firstOne;
            studArray[0] = &firstOne; 
            howMany=0;
            max=5;
        }//myClass()

        void insertEl( Student* nextEl ){
            howMany++;
            if(howMany >= max){
                Student** tempPt = new Student* [max + 1];
                for( int i = 0; i < currentNum; i++){
                    tempPt[i] = studArray[i];       
                }
                delete [] studArray;
                studArray = tempPt; //   <-------------------------error
            }
            studArray[ howMany ] = nextEl;
        }//insertEl
    };
```

I tried changing the original *Student* * array to have no size specified, but that produced the error "incomplete type is not allowed" at *studArray*.

```
    class myClass{
    private:
        Student* studArray[]; <------------- error  
        int howMany;
        int max;
```

What am I doing wrong?
(Thank you for the help!)
For reference I'm using Win 7 64bit, Visual Studio Professional 2012.

Comment: An array can't be on the left-hand side of an assignment. If you want to copy the elements from another array, you have to do so explicitly. If you want to change the location of the array, you have to use a pointer instead.

Comment: `Student* studArray[5];`. Make that `Student** studArray = NULL;`

Comment: _"c++ How to implement a dynamic array of object pointers?"_ as for your questions title: `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Student>>` or ``std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Student>>``.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ sorry, but I'm not familiar with that at all

Comment: You can only `delete[]` something that you `new[]` 'd.

Comment: @Rengetsu _"but I'm not familiar with that at all"_ Well, it's much easier getting _familiar_ with [this stuff](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory), than getting raw pointers, `new` and `delete` correctly yourself. There's other moods where you should _roll your own_.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Oh I bet that's my problem!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Everyone keeps suggesting vectors so I will definitely have to hit the books. As far as this assignment goes I'm going to stick with what we cover in lecture. I'll be tested on pointers/new/delete etc :)

Comment: @Adam I tried that but it said "Data member initializer not allowed" at the equal sign. Does anyone know what I can do to fix it?

Comment: Before C++11 you have to declare it `Student** studArray;` and initialize it in the constructor.

Comment: @Adam you're right, I just found that solution in the book too and I was trying to determine if it would work for my program. If you'd like to post it as an official answer, I think your solution is what answered my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions: Instructor want you to learn the fine art of memory management on your own. So no library containers and no smart pointers. When you have the time, look into how to use the standard containers and the smart pointers. They'll save you a huge amount of time and grief in the future.

First, declaring the Student array.

```
Student* studArray[5];
```

You have the crux of it right here

```
Student** tempPt = new Student* [max + 1];
```

So try

```
Student** studArray;
```

And then hack your constructor to allocate the storage

```
myClass()
{
    max = 5;
    studArray = new Student*[max]; /* For improved safety, read up on
                                      exceptions, catch and handle the 
                                      out of memory exception */
    howMany = 0;
} //myClass()
```

I recommend adding a destructor to handle the clean up and put back your array.

```
virtual ~myClass()
{
    delete[] studArray;
}
```

Check with the assignment notes or the instructor to see who is responsible maintaining the Students. You may have to revisit the destructor to delete all of the Students before deleting `studArray`

Additional note:

```
myClass()
{
    Student firstOne;
    studArray[0] = &firstOne; 
    howMany=0;
    max=5;
}//myClass()
```

`Student firstOne;` is a temporary variable. `firstOne` only exists between the closest enclosing `{}` braces. This is called Scope. Using any value outside of it's scope will have unpredictable results and most likely crash the program. Frankly, that's if you are lucky. The program may limp on for some indeterminate time and crash later.

The assignment `studArray[0] = &firstOne;` is dangerous because by the time anyone tries to use `studArray[0]`, the data at which it points will not be valid. `firstOne`does not exist outside the constructor. If you want `firstOne` to go on living, you will have to define it as a pointer, create it with `new`, and `delete` it when it is no longer needed. In this case I don't think you ever need it.

Another suggestion is to double the size of `studArray` rather then simply adding one when it is full. This way you don't have to reallocate the storage and copy all of the existing students to the new storage as often.

Comment: Thank you for your very thorough answer! I definitely do need to learn this material for the course. I'm especially glad you added that additional note because I was making that same mistake in multiple places. I totally understand the problem there, after throwing in pointers and dynamic memory I ended up forgetting some of the basics too :)

Answer (score 0):

A better method is to have a `std::vector` of `Student`:
  `std::vector<Student *> maleStuds;`
  `std::vector<Student *> femaleStuds;`

Or, if you must use arrays:

```
const unsigned int MAXIMUM_STUDENTS = 5;
Student * students[MAXIMUM_STUDENTS];
```

For dynamic:

```
Student * * students = new Student * [MAXIMUM_STUDENTS];
```

Comment: Don't ask me why, but we skipped the section on vectors. Let me try your array suggestion now.

Comment: Also look up `std::unique_ptr` or search the internet for "boost smart pointers.

Comment: hmm.. are you saying I should put that code in the insertEl function? Or you're saying the original Student* studArray[5]; is the one causing the problem?